# How to plot a grid spec with varying number of rows and columns so that legend and color bar can be visible (not too big or too small)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I hope someone can help me, this is a headache for me that I can't resolve properly.
Assume there is a gripspec with varying number of rows and columns.
You want to include a legend and colorbar below grid or to the right hand side of grid.

How to arrange them so that legend and colorbar can have constant size independent of the number of rows and columns in the grid?
Or proportional to the width of the grid if they are below but visible in case varying number of columns?
Is it possible?

Here is the code below to replicate it.

You can try with

```
x_list = [ i for i in range(1,5)]
y_list = [ 'x'+str(i) for i in range(1,10)]
plot_grid_with_legend_and_color_bar(x_list, y_list)
```

or

```
x_list = [ i for i in range(1,10)]
y_list = [ 'x'+str(i) for i in range(1,5)]
plot_grid_with_legend_and_color_bar(x_list, y_list)
```

And see the difference and my point.

```
import matplotlib.cm as matplotlib_cm
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

def plot_grid_with_legend_and_color_bar(x_list, y_list):
    if len(x_list)>0:
        max_processive_group_length = max(x_list)
        index = x_list.index(max_processive_group_length)

        width = int(2 * len(x_list))
        height = int(2.5 * len(y_list))
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
        fontsize = 35

        grid = plt.GridSpec(ncols=width, nrows=height, hspace=0, wspace=0)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(grid[0:-4, :])  # First axis: Grid with circles
        legend_ax = fig.add_subplot(grid[-3:-2, :])  # Second axis: Legend with circles
        color_bar_ax = fig.add_subplot(grid[-1, :])  # Third axis: Color bar
        ax.set_aspect(1.0)

        cmap = matplotlib_cm.get_cmap('YlOrRd')  # Looks better
        v_min = 2
        v_max = 20
        norm = plt.Normalize(v_min, v_max)

        # To get rid of  UserWarning: Attempting to set identical left==right results in singular transformations; automatically expanding.
        if (len(x_list)>1):
            plt.xlim([1,index+1])
            ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,index+2,1))
        else:
            plt.xlim([0,len(x_list)])
            ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,len(x_list)+1,1))

        if (len(y_list)>1):
            plt.ylim([1, len(y_list)])
        else:
            plt.ylim([0, len(y_list)])

        ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, len(y_list) + 1, 1))

        for y_index, y in enumerate(y_list):
            for x_index, x in enumerate(x_list):
                radius = 0.33
                color = 10
                circle = plt.Circle((x_index + 0.5, y_index + 0.5), radius, color=cmap(norm(color)), fill=True)
                ax.add_artist(circle)

        ax.set_facecolor('white')
        ax.grid(color='black')

        for edge, spine in ax.spines.items():
            spine.set_visible(True)
            spine.set_color('black')

        xlabels = x_list[0:index+1]
        ylabels = y_list

        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        mticks = ax.get_xticks()
        ax.set_xticks((mticks[:-1] + mticks[1:]) / 2, minor=True)
        ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', length=0, labelsize=fontsize)
        if xlabels is not None:
            ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, minor=True)
            ax.set_xlabel('Some Labels',fontsize=fontsize, labelpad=20)
            ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
        ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')

        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        mticks = ax.get_yticks()
        ax.set_yticks((mticks[:-1] + mticks[1:]) / 2, minor=True)
        ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', length=0, labelsize=fontsize)
        ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels, minor=True) # fontsize

        plot_legend_in_given_axis(legend_ax, fontsize / 2)

        # Third part: Color Bar starts
        color_bar_ax.grid(False)
        color_bar_ax.set_xticks([])
        color_bar_ax.set_yticks([])
        for edge, spine in color_bar_ax.spines.items():
            spine.set_visible(False)

        bounds = np.arange(v_min, v_max + 1, 2)

        axins = inset_axes(color_bar_ax,
                           width= "10%",
                           height="10%",
                           loc='center',
                           borderpad=0,
                           bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0, 1, 1),
                           bbox_transform=color_bar_ax.transAxes)

        cb = fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap), cax=axins, ticks=bounds, spacing='proportional', orientation='horizontal')
        cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=fontsize/2)
        cb.set_label("colorbar label", horizontalalignment='center', rotation=0, fontsize=fontsize/2)

        figures_path = os.path.join(os.path.join('/Users', 'burcakotlu', 'Desktop'))
        filename = 'test_%d_%d.png' %(len(x_list), len(y_list))
        figFile = os.path.join(figures_path, filename)
        fig.savefig(figFile, dpi=100, bbox_inches="tight")
        plt.cla()
        plt.close(fig)

def plot_legend_in_given_axis(ax, fontsize):
    diameter_labels = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
    ax.grid(which='major', color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
    ax.set_aspect(1.0)

    ax.set_xlim([0, len(diameter_labels)])
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', length=0, labelsize=12)
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, len(diameter_labels), 1))
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')

    ax.set_xlabel('very long\nlabel', fontsize=fontsize, labelpad=5)
    ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', length=0, labelsize=12)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 1, 1))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: "same width and height" as what?  Also, would you consider minimizing the code above to just show the issue you are having?  You'll get more help that way.

Comment: When you change the number of columns and rows, the color bar squeezes or enlarges, however, I want to see a colorbar which is constant or proportional to the size of the grid. Does it make sense?

Comment: But you use inset_axis with a set percentage of the figure size, and change the figure size, so of course the colorbar changes size.  If you always want it to be the same size, change the 10% to something proportional to figure width.

Comment: With 10%, it is proportional to the width of grid. Isn't it? If there is a way to show the legend and/or color bar in fixed size, I'm open to those solutions.

Comment: If you make it 10% of the width of the "grid" and you make the grid wider or narrower, then the colorbar will "squeeze or enlarge", so it is still not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: ... and again, I will point out that if you removed most of the cruft from your code for the purpose of debugging your issue, you would have a better chance at seeing what is going on.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but no, I do not understand what you want to have happen.    Perhaps you think the 10% is relative to the individual subplots, but it is not - it is relative to your color_bar_ax, which is the full width of the gridspec.  Again, if you want to make the colorbar stay the same size, scale the 10% by the number of columns you have.